# How to fix/repair package dependencies to install Atom

Tags: python, ubuntu, atom-editor

I am running Ubuntu 19.04, and, after downloading and installing Atom via the terminal, I have a red minus-sign on my notification bar and it tells me to run package manager from the right-click menu or from the terminal. 
This is followed by

```
The error message was 'Error: BrokenCount>0
```

which usually means the installed packages have unmet dependencies.

One of the commands I tried running was

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This resulted in the following message:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of atom:
 atom depends on git; however:
  Package git is not installed.
 atom depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5) | libgconf2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
  Package libgconf2-4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package atom (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom
```

What should my next step be?

Comment: Probably want to install the required dependencies as listed: `sudo apt install libgconf2-4`

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend reading "[ask]" and its linked pages, along with "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)".

Comment: As mentioned, install the missing packages.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! When I try to install libconf2-4, it says that I have unmet dependencies, and gives me the same message as before. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get clean
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get -f install
```